# Can I do direct database updates in Django easily?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to write a web application that displays the content of a database as a website, e.g. in the form of a table, and lets the user update the table entries, which should automatically be reflected in the database, so that on page reload, the table looks exactly as the user left it.

Since my web development skills are fairly outdated, I wanted to take this as an excuse to try some new stuff. I know my way around SQL and Python quite well, so I thought Django would be a good choice. I don't have a lot of experience in Javascript however. I already worked through the tutorial, which covers classic HTML forms where you enter a bunch of data and then hit "submit" to push to the database.

What I would really prefer though is to have my whole table freely editable and either immediately save any change to the database (e.g. whenever I click a checkbox or "focus out" of a text box). As a second option I thought about having a single "save" button for the whole page (which may easily be several screens in size).

Now, for the first option, I assume I will likely have to use Javascript and Ajax techniques, which I am not comfortable with them yet, so writing greater pieces of Javascript code is something I am not very keen on at the moment.

For the second option, I would probably have my whole table be a huge, single form with a single submit button. I am a bit wary about this as it does not seem very robust to me.

So what my question boils down to: Are there ways to accomplish what I want in a robust and easy way without having to reinvent the wheel? From my understanding, Django does not cover the final rendering in HTML, it only provides the data, so I would assume I need some third party technology to handle that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for your second idea, submitting the whole table at once, Django has a thing called a `ModelFormSet` where you define a web form which is repeated for each row in the table (or, for the set of records you select).  There are a good amount of basic things you'll need to understand to do it.. eg. how to create a Django view, how to set up a url, how to write templates... but you say you want to learn Django.. so.. it's a good exercise.  The Django documentation has a good tutorial that leads you through development of a basic working app and from there it's not much further to do what you're seeking.

Here's the part of the Django documentation that discusses `ModelFormSet`s:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets

BTW, Django detects which rows have changed so it won't write every row every time, even though you've submitted them all.

Comment: Thanks, that's already a great help. I have finished the tutorial so I am a little familiar with the concept of models, views, urls and templates. I also stumbled across ModelFormSets, but haven't looked at it in detail. Thanks for the hint, I'll check it out.

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks again. It took me an evening to iron out the kinks. I have to replace my object_list in the views with the form set, access form.instance.x if I don't want x editable and I took forever to figure out that I have to set the parameter extra to 0 otherwise Django would add an empty row of data at the end of the table which upon saving would not validate. It works pretty well, I just have to find out how to hande concurrent access to the data as I assume that one person will overwrite the work of another if they press Save before reloading the page.

Comment: Yes they will overwrite, because when you save the modelformset, it compares each row with the corresponding record from the database, and updates any that are different.  But, let's say you have a version number or timestamp on each row, you could put that into a hidden field in your formset and then create a form clean_ method for that field where you check to see if the value is < self.initial, and if it isn't, raise a ValidationError letting the user know they can't change that row.